# Using CBC CLI Arguments in Pyomo

Tags: linear-programming, pyomo, cbc, coin-or

I am currently using the `cbc` solver with Pyomo

```
opt = SolverFactory('cbc')
opt.solve(model)
```

How can more options for Cbc be used, such that what we run using Pyomo is similar to:

```
cbc -cuts off -strong 0 -preprocess off -heuristic off -solve
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `opt.options['Solver parameter to change']='value'`. The following is part of the code that I tried and the generated output:

```
opt.options['heuristics'] = 'off'
opt.options['preprocess'] = 'off'
opt.options['loglevel'] = 50
```

**Pyomo's output:**

command line - ampl cbc heuristics off preprocess off loglevel 50 heuristics off preprocess off loglevel 50 -solve -quit (default strategy 1)

Option for heuristicsOnOff changed from on to off

Option for preprocess changed from sos to off

The list of options for cbc can be found [here](https://ampl.com/products/solvers/all-solvers-for-ampl/).